# Applying Materials To Objects Causes Faces To Turn Transparent

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, 3d-view

I've been using Blender 2.6-2.7 for a few years now, but I've just downloaded 2.81 and jumped in.

The problem I'm experiencing is if I have an object with multiple faces and add more than one material, all the secondary materials applied to faces/vertices/lines turn the faces/vertices/lines the secondary materials applied to transparent.

This happens with new/fresh files, imported files, and files that I append from Blender 2.81 and other versions of Blender from 2.68-2.78. If an object has more than one material, the first material shows, any materials after it show as transparent.

Is this an issue I can fix, or is this a problem with this newer version of Blender, or my older Nvidia Quadro K2100M (2 GB) Graphics Card? I've tried everything I can think of to fix this.

Here is the Blender File Down Below:

[image]

Comment: Could you please try to [update your graphics card driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/155848/en-us) and check if that resolves the problem.

Comment: No good. Rolling back did nothing either. When I get the chance, I may try upgrading if nothing else works. I'll try downloading 2.8 and see if I have the same issue.

Comment: So I'm not having this issue in the portable version of 2.8 I downloaded, but so far, it isn't helping me isolate what the problem may be.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that while it always effects the viewport, it's only when I render with the EEVEE engine that the face doesn't show. Cycles renders the face

Comment: I'll have to take a look at your file, you've likely misconfigured something in Eevee.